# Give ID to View?

Tags: 7, views

How can I give my View an ID? I can give it a class under Advanced pane, but how can I add an ID to a particular View?

Anyone ever bumped into anything like this before

Comment: Other option I found is to use "Global: Custom text". Just to exclude everything from display and do that in Global: Custom text field.

Comment: Gotcha! How do you include everything in Global: Custom text though? What's the 'code' I'll need to use?

Comment: just to make sure the "Global: Custom text" is the last one on the fields list. Then, use the "Replacement Patterns" in "Text" area. for example "<div id="somecustomid">[title][body]</div>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the default template and wrap the view with a div tag and supply an id.

Comment: This is probably a better idea than changing the existing ID on the view div because other things may rely on the default ID that the view div has.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize I could theme by view. Thanks for the tip!